# Gmail suggests old contacts

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Gmail used to put my most used or most recently used addresses at the top of the suggestion box when I type into the "To" field, and now not only does it not put them at the top, but it doesn't even show the best matches. Sometimes I have to type out almost the whole address. Meanwhile the suggestions that do appear are addresses I rarely use. :( What have they changed...and why???

Comment: Only Google can answer that.

Comment: Did you archive any email?